# Selecting Preferred Extension for Syntax Highlighting in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

#### Some background

I am using VS Code as my editor for writing Verilog code, and naturally want syntax highlighting. As such I can choose from one of several extensions which each provide their own highlighting amongst other features.

When I have just one extension installed, lets call it `A`, which provides a nice highlighting scheme, then all is well.

The particular extension `A` is missing some other unrelated features (e.g. linting) which are present in a second extension `B` which I would also like to use. However the syntax highlighting in `B` is inferior.

Naturally when I have both extensions enabled VS Code has two extensions `A` and `B` which both can provide the highlighting for verilog files (`*.v`). Annoyingly VS Code is choosing to use the syntax hightlighting from `B` rather than the one for `A` when both are enabled.

There doesn't appear to be any extension specific setting for disabling the highlighter for extension `B`, and it's not clear how VS Code is selecting which one to use. If it makes a difference the identifier for extension `B` comes after `A` alphabetically.

#### The question

Is there any way to force VS Code to prefer extension `A` over extension `B` to provide syntax highlighting for Verilog files?

Comment: @starball Using `eirikpre.systemverilog` and `mshr-h.veriloghdl`. Both are providing the language ID `verilog` and `systemverilog`.